# Fetch the result from the array value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the table in below description-

```
    +-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| aadhar_no | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_info | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In the user_info I save an array something like this-

```
"poi": {
  "dob": "16-06-1988",
  "gender": "M",
  "email": "some@some.com",
  "name": "some name",
  "phone": "333333333"
},
"poa": {
   "com" : "xyx"
   "other_info" : "others"
}
}
```

Now I need to fetch the aadhar_no if I have "phone". How to achieve this? I am getting lost!

Comment: Transform the data into proper json format and then you can use JSON_CONTAINS_PATH() function.

Comment: @Shadow We can't for now. That is the main issue. Any solution for the same schema?

Comment: You have set yourself up very badly. You can try to come up with some kind of a regexp solution as Darshan Mehta also suggests, but that will be neither efficient, nor totally fool proof. If you want to store a complex data in a field, then follow a standard (xml or json).

Comment: I just need to do this once on my existing database to migrate the data and there is only approx 300 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check whether `user_info` contains `phone` element then you can use `REGEXP` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE details REGEXP '.*.poi.*{.*phone.*}' = 1;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30c02/1/0)**.

**Update**

If you want to search for a specific phone number then, you can wrap the `regex`
into `CONCAT` function and pass the phone number, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test
WHERE details REGEXP CONCAT('.*.poi.*{.*phone".*', '333333333' , '.*}')  = 1
```

Here's the updated **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd0055/2/0)**.

Comment: phone is inside the "poi" key, so doubt this way

Comment: if there is a poi key and the phone is under a different key, then the regexp will match. If the string phone appears anywhere in the array (e.g. as a value, not as a key, or the key contains phone as a substring), then the regexp will still match.

Comment: @darshanmehta I want to fetch the data from the value of phone. For example if i know the value of phone: '3333333' then I need that row.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, but I want result based on the value of phone

Comment: @komalgupta would you mind describing the **whole** issue your are facing? Because it is very impolite to waste the time of those, who would like to help you by revealing further criteria as they try to answer your question. This answer is actually a very good attempt to answer what you **asked for** in your question.

Comment: @Shadow So the issue is I need to update another table based on aadhar_no and I have only phone numbers which are in the table I mentioned, so I need to fetch the adhar_no only. And it's one time job because as you suggested, I am doing the same in another table.

Comment: @komalgupta I agree with Shadow's comment, it would have been better to specify the whole issue upfront. Anyway, I have updated the answer with the above use case.